# Avplayer Tizen controller

Tags: javascript, tizen, avplayerviewcontroller

I am looking for avplayer code that client can control the player on moves ( avplayer controller )
Same like this photo [it's my android version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNXTD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use the **seekTo** function in AVPlay: https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/api-references/samsung-product-api-references/avplay-api.html

> `seekTo`
> Skips playback to a specific timestamp. For HTTP streaming, this method is successful even when the specified timestamp is invalid. The
> internal player automatically resets an out-of-range value to an
> in-range one.
>
> ```
> void seekTo(long milliseconds, optional SuccessCallback? successCallback, optional ErrorCallback? errorCallback);
> ```